If $X_n$ is martingale, $N$ is a stopping time, is $X_{n+N}$ a martingale?
Is this true? If it is, can we change martingale to sub or super?
My attempt (On submartingale): $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+N+1}\vert X_{n+N}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{n+N+1}\vert N,X_{n+N}]\vert X_{n+N}]\ge \mathbb{E}[X_{n+N}\vert X_{n+N}]=X_{n+N}$, therefore $\{X_{n+N}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a submartingale, similar results holds for supermartingale.
My question is, is my attempt above right? If it isn't, is this holds for general stopping  time $N$?

I still don’t understand, how do we see the answer is no by taking $n=0$? Could you please explain more explicitly?

Actually, I think I was thinking about it the wrong way.  Apologies.

$X_{n+N}$ is potentially not even integrable

@Will Why is it may mot be integrable? Do you have any explicit explanation or examples?

We have to know more about $N$. Also, what is the filtration with respect to which you want it to be a Martingale. For example $(X_{n+N}){n\geq 1}$ need not be adapted to the filtration $(\sigma(X{1},...,X_{n})){n\geq 1}$ for a very simple reason. Just take $N$ to be the deterministic stopping time $n$. However, given certain assumptions on $N$, like if it is bounded or not, one can apply the Optional Sampling Theorem to conclude that $X{n+N}$ is a martinagle wrt the natural filtration of the process $X_{n+N}$. But we need to know more.

If $X$ is a right-continuous submartingale and $X_\infty$ exists (i.e., $\mathbb{E}(X_\infty\mid\mathcal{F}_t)\geq X_t$ a.s. for every $t\geq 0$), then $\mathbb{E}(X_T\mid\mathcal{F}_S)\geq X_S$ for any two stopping times $T\geq S$ by the optional sampling theorem, the same being true for (super)martingales. Perhaps there exists modified versions to the optional sampling theorem which reduce the conditions.
